# Youtube embedded video conundrum

Tags: youtube-api

The following fails with "Video Unavailable" even though the API shows `embeddable: true` with no region restrictions.

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M8BlP-nt7kE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Any ideas?

Best,
Andy

Comment: is the video public?

Comment: yes; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8BlP-nt7kE

Comment: mmm this seems to work on websites using https but not on my local host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, I encountered a similar problem that was completely unrelated to the video owners' embedding settings. After some research I found that YouTube has certain restrictions on embedding specific videos within a localhost environment, unless there is a public domain.

You can try embedding the iframe you sent in codepen, for example. As codepen is a public domain, it should display without any problem.
I've already tested it, and it worked fine :)